# Where and how should I store external API access tokens?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt 3 app that uses an external api. When I login my api returns an access token and I use it for future requests.

Currently I set the access token in my pinia store

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia"
import { ref } from "vue"

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", () => {
  const accessToken = ref("")
  
  const setAccessToken = (token: string) => {
    accessToken.value = token
  }

  return { accessToken, setAccessToken }
})
```

If this is a Vue 3 app I would also store the access token in the local storage and use it to set the access token again in the case of page refresh.

But I can't use local storage in this case because it only exist in the browser and my app is rendered on the server.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You can still store them in localStorage. You just have to check for client side execution like `if(process.client) localStorage.setItem(...)`

Comment: @Reyno Ok but when I refresh the page, I can't get it from local storage because the app is being rendered on the server

Comment: You can repopulate the values in the `onMounted` hook and/or wrap certain components in a `<ClientOnly>` component.

Comment: @Reyno So this is the only option I have?

Comment: use cookie to save token

Comment: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie

Comment: @TachibanaShin Thank you for your answer. I used useCookie and everything works perfectly when I run the app on localhost. But when I host it on Netlify I get 500 error (regeneratorRuntime is not defined) Do you have any idea why useCookie causes this error?

Comment: Have you enabled netlify's SSR mode yet?